# Incorrect color getting filled

Tags: gimp

I got an image from here: https://i1.wp.com/www.digitalstreetsa.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/eskomsepush-logo.png?resize=256%2C256&ssl=1

I am trying to fill the red area with a lightgreen shade. I make use of the fill tool. However, when I do so the fill with the color I expect does not get applied.

Am I missing something?

https://youtu.be/U5JxLosgceY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Image > Mode to change the image mode to RGB. Currently, this image is indexed to a limited color map, this helps to reduce the file size considerably.